# Frequency of running chkdsk for a Win7 machine

Tags: windows-7, boot, chkdsk

When I boot up or restart my computer, I sometimes get the countdown timer for running chkdsk and I usually bypass this and boot on into Windows. Is there a good frequency at which to allow your machine to run chkdsk or only when it's seriously needed to check the drive(s) for errors?

Comment: Even *sometimes* is way to often. You should really elaborate why you get these chkdsk prompts. Since that there isn't an optmimal frequency for chkdsk.

Comment: Check this thread for causes of chkdsk: http://superuser.com/questions/226562/what-triggers-a-chkdsk

Comment: If CHKDSK is coming up every time then something might be wrong with your hard drive. Let it run and then restart your computer. Does it still appear? If so, check SMART and see if there are issues with your HDD. Are you running Windows XP? In addition to that, do you shut down your computer properly or hold the power button in? Windows sometimes runs CHKDSK if you shut off the computer incorrectly.

Comment: I must ask, why did this question get downvoted?

Comment: @nixda Thanks for the advice, true it is a case by case basis.

Comment: @simonverbeke, that was a great link to a thorough thread. Definitely something to look back on.

Comment: @sam I've only seen this chkdsk prompt today. The only other times I've seen it was on request and that was several months ago. I bypassed it but maybe i shouldn't have? I'm running windows7. I have held the power button in recently which may have been the cause of this prompt. And lastly, true why was it downvoted? I think my question seems legit.

Comment: If you request it and then pass it should ask on the next reboot. Run one now and then see if it still appears. Run HD Tune (trial) and see if it picks up on any SMART errors. http://www.hdtune.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ALWAYS do a chkdsk when a Windows system advises it be done....wait out the countdown and DO IT.

What this is telling you is that some file system structural error is likely on one of your disks (most likely C: if it is at reboot time) and that you CAN continue but you might further ruin your disk to the point where recovery efforts might not be possible.